# pass xml from jsp to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, xml, jsp

So I have a JSP file which gets an xml file from the session:

```
<%
org.w3c.dom.Document list = (org.w3c.dom.Document) session.getAttribute("list");
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
var list = <%=list %>
</script>
```

And I want to use it in javascript but I can't seem to find a way to load an XML file without providing an URL. The XML file is stored in a database so providing an URL is not possible. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How about loading that whole xml as a string ?

Comment: How can I parse the string in javascript then?

Comment: `var jsString= <%=javaSctring%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First transform your xml `Document` Object to String

```
 <%@ page import="javax.xml.transform.*" %>
 <%
    org.w3c.dom.Document list = (org.w3c.dom.Document) session.getAttribute("list");

    String xmlAsString = "";

    try {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(list), new StreamResult(sw));
        xmlAsString = sw.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error converting to String", ex);
    }
%>
```

Then you can use pass it to a javascript variable (don't forget the quotes):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = '<%=list %>';
</script>
```

Maybe it's also good for you to escape some characters:

```
var list = '<%=list.replaceAll("'","\\'") %>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a two step process, first you need to pass the xml from java to javascript as string, like below

```
var xmlString = "<%=session.getAttribute('list')%>"
```

and then parse the xml string to XMLDocument. Example using jQuery -

```
var xml_doc = jQuery.parseXML(xmlString);
```

For reference :
1. [*jQuery.parseXML()*](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)